# Can I install Workflow Manager In one of my SP servers

Tags: 2013, workflow

I was wondering if I could install SharePoint Workflow manager in one of the Servers where SharePoint 2013 is installed. I couldn't find an example if this kind of infrastructure was possible. All guides had a stand alone server for Workflow manager. 
If this is possible, which server would be appropriate for the installation WFE server of APP services server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes of course you can and the [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj658588.aspx) article recommends you to be considered on both these scenarios.

1. Is Workflow Manager installed on a server that is part of the
   SharePoint farm?
2. Will communication between Workflow Manager and
   SharePoint Server 2013 use HTTP or HTTPS?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can install on an existing SharePoint server or on a dedicated server.